# Problem with building SOAP message on C# WCF DataMember collection

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I am creating a simple WCF Service to accept the SOAP message below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:jvm="http://siph.com/JVM">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <jvm:MT_MedicationOrder>
         <Patientid>?</Patientid>
         <Case_number>?</Case_number>
         <DateTime>?</DateTime>
         <Order>
            <MedicationOrder_id>?</MedicationOrder_id>
            <Descr_of_order>?</Descr_of_order>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Medication_req_type>?</Medication_req_type>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <Infusion_ingredient>
               <Order_Id>?</Order_Id>
               <DrugID>?</DrugID>
               <DrugType>?</DrugType>
            </Infusion_ingredient>
         </Order>
      </jvm:MT_MedicationOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have a problem at <Infusion_ingredient> node that I cannot make it "Zero or more repetitions". Here my partial code for my ServiceContract and DataContract

**ServiceContract**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://siph.com/JVM")]
    public interface IMedicationOrder
    {
        [OperationContract]
        MedicationOrderResponse ProcessOrder(MedicationOrderRequest req);
    }

    [MessageContract(WrapperName = "MT_MedicationOrder")]
    public class MedicationOrderRequest
    {
        //[MessageHeader]
        //public string Dummy;

        #region Message Body
        [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "", Name = "Patientid", Order = 1)]
        public string PatientId;

        [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "", Name = "Case_number", Order = 2)]
        public string CaseNumber;

        [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "", Name = "DateTime", Order = 3)]
        public string RequestDateTime;

        [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "", Name = "Order", Order = 4)]
        public MedicationOrderTransaction OrderTransaction;
        #endregion
    }
```

**MedicationOrderTransaction ServiceContract**

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class MedicationOrderTransaction
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "MedicationOrder_id", Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
        public string MedicationOrderID;
        [DataMember(Name = "Descr_of_order", Order = 2)]
        public string DescriptionOfOrder;
        
        [DataMember(Name = "Medication_req_type", Order = 55)]
        public string MedicationReqType;
        [DataMember(Name = "Infusion_ingredient", Order = 56)]
        public List<InfusionIngredientTransactionList> infusionIngredient;
    }
```

**DataContract InfusionIngredientTransactionList**

```
[DataContract]
    public class InfusionIngredientTransactionList
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Order_Id", Order = 1)]
        public string OrderID;
        [DataMember(Name = "Drug_Id", Order = 2)]
        public string DrugID;
        [DataMember(Name = "DrugType", Order = 3)]
        public string DrugType;
    }
```

**Result: Please notice that a collection of siph:InfusionIngredientTransactionList is created inside Infusion_Ingredient node, not Infusion_ingredient itself that should be a collection.**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:jvm="http://siph.com/JVM" xmlns:siph="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SIPH.WebService.SAP.Model">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <jvm:MT_MedicationOrder>
         <Patientid>?</Patientid>
         <Case_number>?</Case_number>
         <DateTime>?</DateTime>
         <Order>
            <MedicationOrder_id>?</MedicationOrder_id>
            <Descr_of_order>?</Descr_of_order>
            <Medication_req_type>?</Medication_req_type>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Infusion_ingredient>
             <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
             <siph:InfusionIngredientTransactionList>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <siph:Order_Id>?</siph:Order_Id>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <siph:Drug_Id>?</siph:Drug_Id>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <siph:DrugType>?</siph:DrugType>
             </siph:InfusionIngredientTransactionList>
           </Infusion_ingredient>
         </Order>
      </jvm:MT_MedicationOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please suggest me what I have done wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Xml serialization for a list automatically create two xml elements <parent><child/><child/><child/></parent>.  Two prevent two xml element you need to put into the c# class above the list property : [XmlElement()]  Declaring an element will only create one tag.

Comment: I think you can use the message contract, which allows you to specify the precise structure of the SOAP message you need. For more information about message contract, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts

Answer (score 0):

I can't 'Comment' yet, so trying an answer.  So this suggestion may be way off, but would this help:

```
    [DataMember(Name = "Infusion_ingredient", Order = 56)]
    public List<InfusionIngredientTransactionList> infusionIngredient { get; set; } = new List<InfusionIngredientTransactionList>();
```

I also agree that the C# class should go above the List<> property since the class's object is added to the List<> collection. I apologize if not on topic or helpful.